# Evaluate limit of sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-sum

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n + \sqrt{k^2+n}}$$

I saw this as a Riemann Sum and tried to rewrite as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{(\frac{k}{n})^2 + \frac{1}{n}}}$$

but I can't say this is equal to $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$ because there would be a too big error.

The answer should be $\ln 2$.

Comment: You sure it's not an $n^2$ in the original?

Comment: @TehRod Yes, that's why I pointed out the limit is not equal to the integral.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to be an $n^2$, the limit then doesn't even go near $\log(2)$

Comment: One mistake: $(k/n)^2$ becomes $x^2$ in the integral so you should have gotten $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ by your approach. You should instead try to show that you can approximate $1/n$ by $0$ instead, i.e. $\sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/n} \approx \sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 0} = k/n$. This will give you the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{{\rm d}x}{1+x} = \log(2)$.

Comment: @Winther I edited, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squeezing:

$$\frac1{1+\sqrt{\left(\frac kn\right)^2+\frac1n}}\stackrel{(0)}<\frac1{1+\sqrt{\left(\frac kn\right)^2+0}}=\frac1{1+\frac kn}$$

And it is obvious that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac kn}=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x}\ dx=\ln(2)$$

We then notice that:

$$\frac1{1+\sqrt{\left(\frac kn\right)^2+\frac1n}}\stackrel{(1)}>\frac1{1+\frac kn+\frac1{2k}}\stackrel{(2)}>\frac{1-\frac1{2k}}{1+\frac kn}\stackrel{(3)}>\frac1{1+\frac kn}-\frac1{2k}$$

And finally notice that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac kn}-\frac1{2k}\ge\ln(2)$$

which follows easily since

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1k<\frac1n\int_1^n\frac1x\ dx=\frac{\ln n}n$$

and this limit may be taken care of by L'Hospital's rule.

---

$(0)$ is motivated by the inequality $\frac1a<\frac1b$ if $0<b<a$.

$(1)$ is motivated by taking the line tangent to $\sqrt{a+x}$ at $x=0$.

$(2)$ is motivated by taking the line tangent to $\frac1{1+a+x}$ at $x=0$.

$(3)$ is just some basic algebra.

Answer (score 6):

A general approach for such "almost" Riemann sums is to evaluate as a double limit which, in this case, can be justified by uniform convergence of the inner limit:

$$\begin{align} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/n}}  &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/m}}\\ &=   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + (k/n)} \\ &= \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 +x } \\ &= \log 2 \end{align}$$

The relevant theorem is if $x_{nm} \to y_n$ uniformly as $m \to \infty$ and $x_{nm}$ converges as $n \to \infty$, then the double limit exists and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{nn} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty}x_{nm} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}x_{nm}$$

To show uniform convergence in this case, note that

$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/m}}  - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + k/n}   \right| &\leqslant  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{|1 + k/n - (1 + \sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/m})|}{|1+ k/n||1 + \sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/m}|} \\ &\leqslant  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/m}-k/n) \\  &=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{1/m}{\sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/m} + k/n}\\ &\leqslant \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1/m}{1/\sqrt{m}} \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\end{align},$$

showing that

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{(k/n)^2 + 1/m}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + k/n} $$

uniformly for all $n$.

Another approach would be to set bounds and apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: How would you justify changing that $\;n\;$ in the first limit for an $\; m\;$ in the second one? Even more: why would the limit for $\;m\;$ go *first* (from the right)? What and whose uniform convergence are you talking about? We have here discrete variables/running indexes...

Comment: Ok, now I see you actually wrote the relevant theorem at the end of your post. From where is it? Do you have some link to it in some site or book?

Comment: @DonAntonio: It would be in most real analysis textbooks. For example Mathematical Analysis by Apostol (Theorem 9.16) and The Elements of Real Analysis by Bartle (Theorem 19.10).  This establishes the existence of the double limit $\lim_{(n,m) \to (0,0)} x_{nm}$ and equality to iterated limits.  It then can be shown equal to the diagonal limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{nn}$.

Comment: ... and it usually makes short shrift of such "almost" Riemann sums.

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay, woo!  Think I finally completed my answer using squeeze theorem and elementary tangent lines.  :D  Enjoy!

Comment: It might be useful to note that if one simply replace $m$ by $n$ in your estimates then one gets the result directly by squeezing so you already have the ‘other approach’ in here.

Comment: The use Apostol makes of "uniform" convergence for **sequences** in $\;\Bbb N\;$ is unknown to me: I just can't parse it, unless he means he uses some topology there and etc., but I can't then see how this makes sense. Bartle has something similar and he does **not** uses uniform convergence, which seems logical. Just **after** he proves the above he does define "uniform convergence" for sequences, which looks fine then...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + \root{k^{2} + n}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{%
{1 \over n + \root{k^{2} + n}} - {1 \over k + n} + {1 \over k + n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\bracks{%
{k -  \root{k^{2} + n} \over \pars{n + \root{k^{2} + n}}\pars{k + n}} +
{1 \over k + n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\bracks{%
{1 \over k + n} -
{n \over \pars{n + \root{k^{2} + n}}\pars{k + \root{k^{2} + n}}\pars{k + n}}}
\end{align}

> Note that

\begin{align}
&0 < \verts{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}
{n \over \pars{n + \root{k^{2} + n}}\pars{k + \root{k^{2} + n}}\pars{k + n}}} <
n\,{n \over \pars{n + \root{1 + n}}\root{n}n}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,&\ {1 \over \root{n}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to}\,\,\,{\large 0}
\end{align}

> Then,

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + \root{k^{2} + n}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k + n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over 1 + k/n}} =
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over 1 + x} =\
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}