# Compute the following limit, possibly using a Riemann Sum

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-sum

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k+\frac{k}{n^2}}$$ I unsuccessfully tried to find two different Riemann Sums converging to the same value close to the given sum so I could use the Squeeze Theorem. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says $\ln 2$.

Comment: Your answer is nice. Liked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see that

$$ \begin{align}
\left |\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k+k/n^2}-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n+k}\right|&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{(n+k+k/n^2)(n+k)}\\\\
&\le \frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, using $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k =\gamma+\log(n) +O\left(\frac1n\right)$, we see that the limit of the left-hand side of $(1)$ as $n\to \infty$ is $0$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Mark:  Good approach to show the $k/n^2$ is negligible -- which is what this is about.

Comment: @RRL Indeed, although your methd extends beyond just its application to the problem at hand.  Another approach, is to factor $n+k$ out of the denominator and bound the term $\frac1{1+k/(n^2(n+k))}$ on both sides then apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 10):

Writing this as

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}S_{nn} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\frac{1}{n^2}}
$$

a technique that often works is to evaluate the double limit

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{mn} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\frac{1}{m^2}} = \lim_{m \to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 +x + x/m^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1 +x}
$$

where the last step is justified by DCT.

We can justify  $ \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{nn} = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{mn} = \log 2$ by showing one of the iterated limits  exhibits uniform convergence.

An example with more details is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2259535/148510).  The argument for justifying the use of the double limit in this case will be similar.

Comment: This is pretty brilliant! Had never seen this technique.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2259535/148510) is an example with the full justification.  Thanks.

Comment: Well done.  And the general result is more powerful than its application here.  I posted a solution with a simpler way forward.  Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim _{n \to \infty }\sum _{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + k + k/n^{2}}} =
\lim _{n \to \infty }\bracks{{n^{2} \over n^{2} + 1}
\sum _{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over k + n^{3}/\pars{n^{2} + 1}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim _{n \to \infty }\braces{{n^{2} \over n^{2} + 1}
\sum _{k = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{{1 \over k + n^{3}/\pars{n^{2} + 1}} -
{1 \over k + n^{3}/\pars{n^{2} + 1} + n}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim _{n \to \infty }\braces{{n^{2} \over n^{2} + 1}
\bracks{H_{\large n^{3}/\pars{n^{2} + 1} + n}\ -\
H_{\large n^{3}/\pars{n^{2} + 1}}}}
\end{align}
where $\ds{H_{z}}$ is a [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

> In using the
>   [$\ds{H_{z}}$  asymptotic behavior as $\ds{\verts{z} \to \infty}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation), it's straightforward found:

$$
\bbx{\lim _{n \to \infty }\sum _{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + k + k/n^{2}} = \ln\pars{2}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

> I thought it might be instructive to present a method that relies only on the **squeeze theorem**.  To that end, we proceed.

---

First, it is trivial to see that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k+k/n^2}\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}\tag 1$$

---

Second, note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k+k/n^2}&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(n+k)\left(1+\frac{k/n^2}{n+k}\right)}\\\\
&\ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(n+k)}\left(1-\frac{k/n^2}{n+k}\right)\\\\
&\ge \left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

Putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together reveals

$$\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k+k/n^2}\le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k+k/n^2}=\log(2)$$

as expected!

Answer (score 0):

The sum under limit is not a Riemann sum, but it differs from a Riemann sum by negligible amount.

To setup things let's note that by definition of Riemann integral we have $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(t_k),\,\frac{k-1}{n}\leq t_k\leq \frac{k} {n} $$ It is easy to guess that the function $f$ involved here is given by $f(x) =1/(1+x)$ and let's choose $$t_1=0,t_k=\frac{k-1}{n}+\frac{k-1}{n^3},k=2,3\dots,n$$ The corresponding Riemann sum is $$S_n=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{k-1}{n}+\dfrac{k-1}{n^3}}$$ which can be rewritten as $$S_n=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n+k+(k/n^2)}$$ If the sum in question is denoted by $S'_n$ then we can see that $$S_n-S'_n=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+n+(1/n^2)}$$ and clearly the above expression tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty $. The Riemann sum $S_n$ tends to $\int_{0}^{1}dx/(1+x)=\log 2$ and hence the given sum $S'_n$ also tends to $\log 2$.

The same technique has been used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3168198/72031) in a simpler manner.