# Is it alright to substitute $0$ for $1/n$ in this limit problem?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{2n + 2r-1}$

To solve this I used the following approach: 
\begin{align} S &= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{\frac 1n}{2 + 2\frac rn-\frac1n} \\
&= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{\frac 1n}{2 + 2\frac rn-\color{red}{0}} = \dfrac 12\int _0^1 \dfrac{1}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x \\ &= \ln(\sqrt 2)\end{align}

Though the answer is correct, I am unsure about my second step in which I have replaced $1/n$ by $0$. *Is that allowed?* I have tried it in some other problems too and it works.

Comment: Just because some arbitrary manipulation leads to the correct answer in some cases, does not mean that it leads to the correct answer in other cases.

Comment: I'm glad you ask this question, instead of assuming that what works is right. Though for the sake of your mathematical learning, next time it is better if you ask "Why should it be true?" instead of "Is it allowed?" Mathematics is not founded upon laws with penalties if they are broken. Rather, (at least some part of) mathematics is the endeavour to deduce true statements about the real world. You can write whatever symbols you want on paper, and unsound methods can be accepted by people in general, but it won't change reality.

Comment: If things are continuous you can replace $\lim f(combined)g(n)$ whith $f(combined)[\lim g(n)]$ but you can not replace $\lim f(n)(combined)g(n)$ withe $\lim f(n)(combined)(\lim f(n))$.  So no.  This is not valid.

Answer (score 10):

"That" is not allowed in general.

It works here because you can squeeze the sum by two Riemann sums for the same function $\frac{1}{2(1+x)}$ on the same interval $[0,1]$:

$$\small\frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{1 + \frac{r}{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{2n + 2r} \leq \sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{2n + 2r-1} \leq \sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{2n + 2r-2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{1 + \frac{r-1}{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 9):

By definition of Riemann integral we have $$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}f(t_r)$$ where $t_r$ lies between $(r-1)/n$ and $r/n$. For the current question the given sum matches $f(x) =\dfrac{1}{2(1+x)}$ and $t_r=(2r-1)/2n$. Thus the desired limit is indeed equal to $(1/2)\log 2$.

---

The notion of a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) is far more general than usual calculus texts will lead you to believe (most calculus texts either keep $t_r=(r-1)/n$ or $t_r=r/n$). The sum in question is a Riemann sum as explained above.

---

Also in mathematics one can't replace $A$ by $B$ unless $A=B$. If you see some replacements which work out fine but look mysterious then you just need to understand that some steps are missing.

---

The technique can be used to handle sums which are not exactly Riemann sums but differ slightly from it. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3169012/72031) for an example.

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not allowed, because for all you know that $\frac 1 n$ could have some subtle interaction with the rest of the formula which cancels out its going to zero. For example in the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}n\frac1n$$

we can't just replace $\frac1n$ with $0$ (yielding a limit of $0$) because the presence of the factor $n$ cancels that out. How do you know there isn't something you didn't spot in your formula which produces similar behavior? Maybe the $\frac rn$ or the $\frac 1n$ in the numerator has a similar "cancelling" effect on the $\frac 1n$ which you're trying to replace with $0$.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better and safer to bound the limit from both sides as following:$$\alpha n+2r<2n+2r-1<2n+2r$$for every $\alpha<2$ and $n$ sufficiently large. Therefore$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}{1\over 2 n+2r}<\sum_{r=1}^{n}{1\over 2n+2r-1}<\sum_{r=1}^{n}{1\over \alpha n+2r}$$Now fix $\alpha<2$. Therefore by integrating we obtain$${1\over 2}\ln 2\le\text{the desired limit}\le {1\over 2}\ln{2+\alpha\over\alpha}$$Since the latter holds for every $\alpha<2$, then we can write $$\text{the desired limit}={1\over 2}\ln 2$$

Comment: As [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3168268/446262) explains, no, that is *not* correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you. I got that point.